# What is equivalent of FXLocal.getContext() in javafx 2.1?

Tags: javafx, javafx-2

What is equivalent method of this in javafx 2.1? What is use of this? Please give brief explanation. Code of javafx 1.3 is here..

```
  def context = FXLocal.getContext();
```

Comment: I don't know what this is about, but some superficial googling makes me think step five here might be relevant to what you are asking: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/zonski-1508195.html getbean insted of getcontext etc.

Comment: Thanks Unfun. But this is not helpful for me. Please give another suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It gets a context for querying class and object metadata for the virtual machine.  It can be used both similarly to the Java reflection classes and also as a low level API a debugger can integrate with to debug a program.

The most common thing you would do in a Java analog of this is perform reflection, for which you can read [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html).

For info on the far less common and technically hardcore debugger interface, you could [google com.sun.jdi.VirtualMachine](http://www.google.com/search?q=com.sun.jdi.VirtualMachine).

Comment: Thanks @Jewelsea. But i am not know, how to use this class and this class is not in sdk7. So please explain.

Comment: I found jar. This jar is in lib of sdk and solved my problem. Thanks @jewelsea again.